# How to fix thread completely stopping other threads with no error

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am attempting to run a side thread to collect data from the 1st thread, however, the side thread "Thread 3" is stopping all functionality altogether. I thought threads were supposed to run at the same time? I need help in understanding what is going on.

I have tried removing thread 3's creation altogether and that allows complete functionality again, however as soon as I readd it even if the start function is after other functions, it still proceeds to stop everything.

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, Semaphore
import datetime
from packet_reader import Rip
import time

# queue.PriorityQueue.
global switch


class NewThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self, name="My First Thread")

    def run(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("This is: {0} at {1}".format(self.getName(), now))


class Switch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vlan_100_0 = queue.Queue()
        self.vlan_100 = queue.Queue()
        self.vlan_101_0 = queue.Queue()
        self.vlan_101 = queue.Queue()

    def sort_by_vlan(self, f):
        with open("log", "w") as log:
            thread_output = Thread(target=output(log), name="Sort Thread")  # Thread 3 creation
            for line in f:
                if Rip().get_vlan_id(line) == 100:
                    if Rip().get_priority(line) == 0:
                        self.vlan_100_0.put(line)
                    elif Rip().get_priority(line) == 2:
                        temp_packetobject = Rip()
                        thread_alert = Thread(target=alert(line, temp_packetobject, log), name="Sort Thread")
                        thread_alert.start()
                        self.vlan_100.put(line)
                    # send message to interuppt handler

                elif Rip().get_vlan_id(line) == 101:
                    if Rip().get_priority(line) == 0:
                        self.vlan_101_0.put(line)
                    elif Rip().get_priority(line) == 2:
                        temp_packetobject = Rip()
                        thread_alert = Thread(target=alert(line, temp_packetobject, log), name="Sort Thread")
                        thread_alert.start()
                        self.vlan_101.put(line)
                    # Send message to interrupt handler

        while self.vlan_100_0.empty() is False:
            self.vlan_100.put(self.vlan_100_0.get())

        while self.vlan_101_0.empty() is False:
            self.vlan_101.put(self.vlan_101_0.get())

        thread_output.start()
        del self.vlan_100_0
        del self.vlan_101_0
        return


lock = Lock()  # Creating the Threading lock


def startx():  # Thread 1

    with open("file", "r") as f:
        switch.sort_by_vlan(f)
    # print(x) Used for debugging


def alert(packet, packetobject, log):  # Thread 2

    packetinfo = packetobject.get_src_mac(packet) + " " + packetobject.get_dest_mac(packet) + " TIME:" + str(datetime.datetime.now())

    with lock:
        print("Obtained lock for alert")
        log.write("ALERT -- PRIORITY PACKET --- " + packet + " --- " + packetinfo + "\n\n")
        print("ALERT -- PRIORITY PACKET --- " + packet + " --- " + packetinfo + "\n\n")


def output(log):  # Thread 3
    print("got to log")
    with lock:
        print("Obtained lock for output")
        packet = switch.vlan_100.get()  # This line stops everything for some reason
        log.write("QUEUED PACKET --- " + packet) + " --- " + Rip().get_src_mac(packet) + " " + Rip().get_dest_mac(packet) + " TIME:" + str(datetime.datetime.now() + "\n\n")
        print("QUEUED PACKET --- " + packet + " --- " + Rip().get_src_mac(packet) + " " + Rip().get_dest_mac(packet) + " TIME:" + str(datetime.datetime.now() + "\n\n"))


switch = Switch()
thread_sort = Thread(target=startx, name="Sort Thread")  # Thread 1 creation
thread_sort.start()


# nice
```

Expected results should be the 3rd thread running at the same time as thread 1 and going back and forth between thread 2 and thread 3 with the lock. writing data to the log file and screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of problems:

- the most important one, when you instantiate a `Thread` you are doing it wrong,
  because you are calling `Thread(target=threadfunction())` instead of `Thread(target=threadfunction)` with extra `()` which basically means that you are calling the `threadfunction` and giving the `Thread` target the result of the `threadfunction` call which is basically `None`. Now I understand that you want to pass some arguments to the thread when you create it but you need to pass them via the `args` parameter of the `Thread` constructor. [more information about the Thread arguments here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).
- that is also the reason why your code stucks at `switch.vlan_100.get()`, because you call the `output` function before you add items to the `self.vlan_101` later in `sort_by_vlan`, and the default behaviour of the `Queue` is to wait on `get` until it gets some items into it from somewhere. -> take care here as if you don't check if the queue is empty you might end stuck again even if you correct these bad calls
- you are creating `thread_alert` multiple times. Kind of beats it's purpose, you should be using a queue between the main switch thread and the `thread_alert` and just feed the packets to it